# How to inject an entire html file inside div tag in angular 8?

Tags: javascript, angular, innerhtml

in my angular component i have a div. i have to render some html file inside it. i have used [innerHtml]. it is actually rendering. but the problem is i couldnt call script functions. there are console error like the function is undefined.

Eg:
my html is

````
    <head>
        <script>
            function callmefunction() {
                alert("Hi, Good morning");
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <button onclick="callmefunction()"> Click here </button>
    </body>
</html>```

I can see the button and i can see scripts function when i inspect element too. but i couldnt call callmefunction() when i click that button. i am getting this follwing console err
"Uncaught ReferenceError: callmefunction is not defined
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick"

P.S - I am using safeHTML Pipe 

My code is,
```<div [innerHTML]="howItWorks | TrustHtml" class="col-md-12">```

i ll be very grateful if someone could help me....
````